# Obj-C: It changes center before rotating

Tags: objective-c

It's my code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                      delay:0.1f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( 30.0 / 180.0 * 3.14 );
                     [needleBig setTransform:rotate];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
```

And it's the pictures before and after rotating:
[image: Before rotating]
[image: After rotating]

It seems it changes center before rotating, but I don't want it.

Answer (score 3):

A rotation created with `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle)` makes a rotation of the coordinate system around its origin. The docs say "angle = The angle, in radians, by which this matrix rotates the coordinate system axes."
From your pictures it looks as if the origin of your coordinate system is somewhere at the top left corner of the square enclosing your clock.
You can rotate about any other point if you set the view's layer's `anchorPoint` property accordingly.

Comment: I've added                          `needleBig.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(needleBig.center.x, needleBig.center.y);`
 but it disappears the image!

Comment: You could check, e.g. in the debugger, where the center of your needleBig view is. Or you could slow down your animation so that you can see about which point your view is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
needleBig.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                      delay:0.01f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(180.0f * (M_PI / 180.0f));

                    [needleBig setTransform:rotate];



                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){


                 }];
```